# In Grails, how do I declare a SQL Server Schema name for a Domain Class?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have recently started reading up on Grails and would like to use SQL Server security schemas to group tables generated by GORM. However, I cannot seem to find a reference explaining how to perform this task. I am new to Hibernate as well and would like to know if this is possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this when you explicitly specify the mapping in a domain class as [described here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/table.html):

```
class Book {
    static mapping = {
        table name:"books", schema:"dbo"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you for that link. Will GORM create the Schema as well? If not, what is the best practice in Grails surrounding this type of design?

Comment: I haven't actually used schemas like this, but it shouldn't be hard to find out by tring.

Comment: I will give it a try. I appreciate your feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Michael Borgwardt is technically correct, but be aware that as of Grails 1.3.4, there is still a bug where using table-per-class inheritance all child classes will ignore the schema definition.

A possible work-around is to name the entire table and include the schema thus: "dbo.books", however this can cause problems with referential integrity; GORM will try to construct a name which contains too many "." characters, and PostgreSQL (for one) thinks you're trying to create cross-database server referential integrity, which isn't supported.